# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in Python when reading "gz" file

Tags: python

I have a folder which involves `".gz"` files.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt, os

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath = '/export/students/sait/yedek'

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

size = []

for a in range(len(onlyfiles)):
        print onlyfiles[a]
        size.append(os.path.getsize(onlyfiles[a]))
        print size[a]
```

When I want to read the sizes, I get such an error:

```
"OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rgb-0.ppm.gz'"
```

Where is this smart problem?

Comment: Surprising problem, but I have only an advice for you to improve your for loop: `for file in onlyfiles:` `print(file); size.append(os.path.getsize(file)); print(size[-1])` - this iterates directly over the list elements instead of the indexes which is usually the way to go in Python.

Comment: Doesn't look like you are actually adding your joined path to the list, just f. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onlyfiles` contains basename of the files, not the full paths to them. (and your working directory seems to be not `mypath`).

You either need to fix `onlyfiles` creation:

`onlyfiles = [join(mypath, f) for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]`

or you can also `os.chdir(mypath)` before your `for`-loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt, os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'/export/students/sait/yedek')
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
size = []
for file in onlyfiles:
        print file
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file)
        print file_size
        size.append(file_size)
```

try this this is working for me